# Grab Lists from Database then Grab Top Tags In Each List

Tags: php

So, let's say I have a database where users can add "tags" that PHP turns into a comma separated list. The user puts in 'Orange, Peppers, Biscuits Onions Grapes' and It turns into 'orange,peppers,biscuits,onions,grapes'. Now, I'm pretty sure that will be easy enough, and I don't need help there. But now these "tags" are listed in the SQL Database.

```
$individuallist = $databaserow['database_list'];
$arrayoflist = explode(',', $individuallist );

foreach($arrayoflist as $individualtag) {

//Display Tags

}
```

So, good, I can grab these tags and use them for the specific item they relate to and I can take the list and turn it into an array and foreach them to display each individual one.

However, I need to take all the lists in the database and add them together. For example:

```
while($databaserow = mysql_fetch_assoc($databaseresult)) {

$database_array[] = $databaserow ['database_list'];

}
```

So these two example lists will be combined into an array

```
// The Two Lists
// 'orange,peppers,biscuits,onions,grapes'
// 'peppers,orange,market,turkey,juice'

$database_full_list = implode(',', $database_array);

// The Full List
// 'orange,peppers,biscuits,onions,grapes,peppers,orange,market,turkey,juice'
```

Now that I have the full list of tags, I need to count to see which Tags are the Top 30. The idea is that as more tags are added to the database, the Top 30 Tags would be listed in order of how many there are of them.

Orange (2)

Peppers (2)

Bisquits (1)

Market (1)

etc.

I don't know how to this part of the coding.

Comment: Please provide an example database schema for us to answer with. Are you also asking for how to turn the two lists of strings into one, or do you know that already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$split_tags = explode(',', $database_full_list);
$count_tags = array();

foreach($split_tags as $tag) {
    if(!array_key_exists($tag, $count_tags))
        $count_tags[$tag] = 0;

    $count_tags[$tag]++;
}

asort($count_tags);

foreach(array_reverse($count_tags) as $tag => $count)
    echo "$tag ($count)<br/>";
```

Comment: I'll have you realize that split is deprecated. You should be using explode. Though, this did do what I wanted.

Comment: However, as I just realize, how do I limit by 30 Tags?

Comment: Well done figuring that out yourself :) I'll update it to use explode instead - sorry, keep mixing myself up with other languages